# imgmount in dosbox says "can't create drive from file" to .img created with dd

Tags: linux, mount, images, floppy, dosbox

**Background:**

I want to backup old floppy disks (as images) and then be able to mount them in dosbox later.

**What I did:**

1. I'm running Linux Mint.
2. I add an external 3,5" floppy drive (USB)
3. I dump an image of a floppy using: `dd if=/dev/sdb of=disk.img`
4. I start dosbox (still on Linux)
5. Doing `imgmount a ~/disk_images/disk.img -t floppy` results in "Can't create drive from file" message from dosbox.

**I also tried:**

- I tried without the "-t floppy".
- If I (on purpose) misspell the image file name, dosbox says "The image must be on a host or local drive." (so I point to the correct image file).
- I tried copying the floppy using `cat /dev/sdb > disk.img` as well. Still the same result.

How do I create proper images?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, after some research I realized that the whole issue was caused by something as simple as Linux ownership. Apparently I had created the file as root user, so when trying to do `imgmount` with one of my other users I couldn't mount that image in dosbox.

Simple as that! :-)

Thanks for all response (@erreka).

Comment: Please add that the mode has to be right: after some testing I found that, besides owner permission, if the img file is in executable mode it cannot be mounted. Tested on TinyCore Linux.

Comment: Had a similar problem on Windows, it turned out that the .img files were set as read-only.